# Insert into table when the day is Monday

Tags: sql, sql-server, case-when

Is there a way in which I can insert data from one table into another when today is Monday?

I tried making something like the below, using `CASE WHEN`, however it doesn't quite work right, any help would be welcomed

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[WF_All]

SELECT (CASE WHEN (DATENAME(WEEKDAY,FLOOR(convert(float,getdate()))))='MONDAY' THEN  

(
SELECT [Parent Number]
  ,[Parent Name]
  ,[Customer Number]
  ,[Customer Name]
  ,[Collector]
  ,[Outstanding]

   FROM dbo.[Invoices]
 )

  ELSE  NULL END )
```

Comment: You would want to put your condition in a `where` clause in order to filter out rows (all or none.) In that case get rid of the `case`. And I doubt you need that conversion to strip out the time component. Just use the date functions to extract day of week from the original date value. If this is inside a batch/proc then look at `if` for true branching behavior.

Comment: `CASE` is an **expression**. T-SQL does not support `Case` (`Switch`) statements.

Comment: This is orchestration/scheduling, not SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes , like this :

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[WF_All]
SELECT [Parent Number]
  ,[Parent Name]
  ,[Customer Number]
  ,[Customer Name]
  ,[Collector]
  ,[Outstanding]
FROM dbo.[Invoices]
WHERE DATENAME(WEEKDAY,GETDATE()) = 'Monday'
```

or

```
... WHERE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) = 2 --Monday
```

Comment: Right, knew it would have had an easier solution to what I was looking for. Also, now I see my pointless conversions.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want.

```
if datename(weekday,getdate()) = 'MONDAY' then
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[WF_All] (
        -- column names go here
    )
    SELECT [Parent Number]
      ,[Parent Name]
      ,[Customer Number]
      ,[Customer Name]
      ,[Collector]
      ,[Outstanding]
   FROM dbo.[Invoices]
```

Comment: column names are not necessary

Comment: They may not be strictly necessary on your platform. But they do serve a purpose and you'd be foolish to leave them out.

Comment: @RomanMarusyk but listing the column names **is** best practice.